# C# Regex to return only the letters

Tags: c#, regex

I am having a few problems with regex in C#.  I require a string to be passed in and only the letters to be returned (as a string), so for example if the string is "4hr", I want "hr" to be returned.  If the string is "Gp. 23", I just want "Gp" to be returned.

I've tried:

```
 string[] extractedWords = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(expr, "[a-zA-Z]");
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want just a string to be returned, using split is a bad idea. How about:

```
string filtered = Regex.Replace(expr, "[^A-Za-z]", "");
```

In other words "replace anything that isn't A-Z or a-z with an empty string". Note that that will *also* strip non-ASCII letters; you *may* want to use a Unicode character class (e.g. "letter") instead.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks Jon.  I've only really just begun to learn about this concept.  Will do some further reading over the next few days.